# Salesforce DX referring to Global picklist "CustomField not found."

Tags: custom-field, salesforcedx, scratch-org, global-picklist

I have successfully deployed a Global Picklist "State" in scratch Org.
Following deployment I am referring the global picklist in a custom field.
I am get the following deployment error

API Name : State
Type : Global Value Set
Error Message : CustomField not found.

Please let me know what is causing the issue and what I need to do to correct it. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved.  I did a source pull again from scratch Org. It updated the Global Valueset locally and followed with push made a successful deployment
I will try to get the root cause shortly and post it